# what is the difference between log and ln?

Tags: logarithm

can I write a log in place of ln in statistics? I have seen people telling me that logarithm differs from natural logarithm. Is it correct?

Comment: For some odd reason $\log$ is used interchangeably with $\ln$ in statistical literature.  Both are understood to be the inverse of the exponential function $\exp(x)$.  Just a weird quirk of stats.

Answer (score 2):

The logarithm operator takes multiple bases, the natural logarithm is simply the logarithm operator with base $e$, Euler’s number. In a lot of disciplines, $log$ is regularly used in place of $ln$. I would, in practice, specify when using it that way though.